# How a query can verify itself that all template parameters are replaced before executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In sql query can it verify itself that all template parameters are replaced before someone can execute the query.

I came up with an idea to check params like this in the beginning of each query:

```
IF ( '<Template param,'+
    ',Value>' = '<Template param,,Value>' )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (N'Please, first fill template parameter: <Template param,,Value>', 18, -1, N'');
END
```

But this way i should check every param one by one.
Is there more intelligent way to do this?

Comment: This should be done in the application code, not in SQL.

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL Server, use Stored Procedures instead of ad-hoc queries (a good idea anyway) and make all of the parameters non-optional.  SQL Server will handle the rest for you.

Comment: Stored procedures wouldn't do the job, cause the queries are executed on a remote environment by DBA's and i need to make sure that on execution the query has no templates left. And i dont want to make a special app to execute them :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the params with actual variables, but not actually declare the variables? That way, if they haven't replaced the variable with the desired values, the parser will complain about the variable not being initialized.

```
IF ( @Template_param + @Value = @Template_param_Value )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, 18, -1, N'');
END
```